Azure Data Factory Expression Builder: Error Structuring JSON with Nested Arrays and Objects
I've been working on this for a couple of days now and am reaching out for assistance. I was unable to structure the format properly and need help.
I've been trying to create a JSON structure in Azure Data Factory (ADF) using the Expression Builder, but I'm encountering an error. Here's the JSON structure I want to achieve:
{
  "entity_id": "value1",
  "link_id": "value2",
  "url": "value3",
  "actions": [
    {
      "appointment_info": {}
    }
  ]
}

In the Expression Builder, I structured it as follows:
@(entity_id=entity_id,
  link_id=link_id,
  url=url,
  actions=[@(appointment_info=@())])

However, I receive an error at the line actions=[@(appointment_info=@())], specifically at @() right after appointment_info=. This should work, but it's still showing an error in ADF, and I'm unable to structure it as intended:
"actions": [
  {
    "appointment_info": {}
  }
]

Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong and how to correctly format this JSON structure in ADF's Expression Builder? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Are you using ADF pipeline expression builder or ADF dataflow for this? and what is your target database here? Is it a SQL database or a JSON file to blob or gen2?

Hi @RakeshGovindula , In ADF Dataflow, I'm using derived column to structure JSON using the expression builder. This JSON is then processed into a file and saved to Blob storage.

In the Expression Builder, I structured it as follows:
@(entity_id=value1,
    link_id=value2,
    url=value3,
    actions=[@(appointment_info=@(appointment_null=appointment_null))])

I added a new column in the source's select query and fetched a null value. Since the column has null for all rows, it will always display as {}. However, this won't work for an empty string.

select '' appointment_empty, null appointment_null from .........

appointment_empty would display the column name and appointment_null would'nt.

You can make your answer as accepted, since it might help the other community members who goes through the same issue.

@RakeshGovindula: This doesn’t read like a (complete) answer, but rather something they tried that made some progress, but still have issues. Or am I misreading it? Perhaps this is an answer, just with some acknowledged limitations? Regardless, an [edit] would clarify the intent.


However, I receive an error at the line actions=[@(appointment_info=@())], specifically at @() right after appointment_info=

I have tried the same expression, and it is saying incorrect parsing error. It seems like ADF dataflow derived column expression doesn't support empty objects.
If you have access to Blob or Gen2 storage account, you can try the below workaround to achieve the requirement.
First use the below expression in the derived column transformation.
replace(toString(@(entity_id=entity_id,
link_id=link_id,
url=url,
actions=[@(appointment_info='my_str')])),'"my_str"','{}')

As it doesn't support empty object, the above expression first generating required JSON with "my_str" string in the place of {}. Then replace it by {} and get the JSON string in a column.

Next, use select transformation and remove the extra columns.

In the dataflow sink, take a delimited text dataset and give the below configurations. This dataset should be from Gen2 or blob.

Don't give any file name for this in the dataset. Give filename as filename.json in the dataflow sink settings.

Here, we are using the delimited text dataset to generate the JSON file from the JSON string that we created. As we unchecked First row as header, it will give the JSON file as expected.
Result file:

But in the later usage of this file in ADF, you need to create another JSON dataset pointing to this location.

Thank you, @RakeshGovindula. The solution you posted worked. I am able to get the data as you have shown in the last screenshot of targetjson1.json. However, I have an aggregate function right before the sink that performs a collect function on the data, so that I receive the expected data as I have posted in the next comment. If I remove this aggregate function, I am receiving data as you posted in the screenshot. But, I need this comma separated list format.

{
"data": [
{
"entity_id": "value1",
"link_id": "value2",
"url": "value3",
"actions": [
{
"appointment_info": {}
}
]
},
{
"entity_id": "value1",
"link_id": "value2",
"url": "value3",
"actions": [
{
"appointment_info": {}
}
]
}
]
}

AFAIK, it's not possible to get the empty object data in the dataflow. One thing you can do is, store the data as JSON file and then use another dataflow after that and process that as per your aggergation.

After converting it to JSON string, I have tried to convert it back to JSON using parse transformation. But it's giving the same error as it's an empty JSON object. So, using the JSON from the file might work to get your requirement done.

Thank you, Rakesh for researching into this. Really appreciate your time and effort. I tried it all. The only issue was when aggregating/collecting the data. However, I found a workaround to achieve the same. Will post that as an answer.
